# How to show a from view from a field in another form in openerp

Tags: openerp-7

I am very new to openerp, I want to load a view from a field in another view in openerp as shown in fig. Can anyone say how to bring it?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they doing it by declaring the field from python as Many2one field?? 
Can anyone say which attribute to the field from server side.

Comment: here supplier is a many2one field, thats why it open to form of that object. Can you explain your use?

Comment: Yes, if you define the field as many2one in python, it will meet your requirement.

Comment: Thanks But what if it is not a many2one field, say like what if it is a reference field in invoice which could be either incoming shipment or po ??